# Understand sizeof in relation to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

In my C++ class my teacher gave me this code.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    char numbers[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
            11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
    char *ptrNumber;
    ptrNumber = &numbers[0];

    // Address of first and last index
    cout << (size_t)(ptrNumber) << " to " << (size_t)(ptrNumber + 17) << endl;
}
```

Which prints

```
12647972 to 12647989
```

Now previously I thought that the size of a pointer to a char would have 1 byte, meaning that both `(size_t)(ptrNumber)` and `(size_t)(ptrNumber+17)` would print 1. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This is not the `sizeof` operator, you just casted the value (memory address) of the pointer to the type named `size_t` (which is the return type of sizeof)

Comment: You have a comment above your output 'Address of first and last index' and that is what you are printing. Was that the request of the assignment?

Comment: @lakeweb i just copied and pasted the code from the slides, but now I understand that I was confusing sizeof with size_t

Comment: It still won't print 1. As mentioned, it will print 4 or 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're printing is not the size of the pointer (which btw is usually 4 or 8 bytes), but the address that the pointer stores. So the program displays the memory address where the first and last elements are located. `size_t` here has nothing to to with the `sizeof` operator; you only perform a cast. If you remove the `size_t`, you'll end up printing the string that's represented by the char array. But because your array doesn't represent a legal C-string (no zero terminator and non-displayable characters), you'll most likely end up with a segfault.

Comment: `char*` does not print hex to cout.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks, corrected, missed the `char` part for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is one byte, the pointer to a character typically occupies 32 bits (4 bytes) or 64 bits (8 bytes) depending on your machine and environment. It is an address in the end.